# How to create an arch entance with curves designs?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

How to model this arch entrance? I have successfully created the overall arch, but adding those curve designs (in the red circle) is my challenge.
My final goal is to completely model this entrance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could simply follow the curves with the vertices like this:

[image]

Comment: WOW that's great ,any little or more explanation on the how you traced that, probably the tools or key combinations. maybe an animated GIF might help. sorry im a beginner but anyway thanks for the clues you gave

Comment: @jugnu, if you are satisfied with this answer and if is enough, click tick to award 10 points to Moonboots.

Comment: i can guess the process now , trace the image , extrude to form a mesh , extrude the curve design , mirror the half entrance and apply smooth modifiers. Thanks

Comment: Hello Jugnu, it would take a lot of explanation to explain everything in detail, please tell me where you have met problems. To make it short: Use your picture as a background image, create a plane, keep only one vertex, mirror it, extrude along the curves, use S + Axis + 0 when you want to flatten on an axis, extrude in depth, give it a Subdivision Surface modifier and click the Smooth Shading option, add some edge loops along the curves with ctrl R in order to sharp the edges... and generally create a topology that will allow you to add those additional edge loops.